# Cleanest way to assign to a variable if an element in jsoup is defined?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, jsoup

I was doing this `String name = doc.select("h1#name").first().text();` and I received a NullPointerException on a page where the 'h1#name' element did not exist. I'm parsing the DOM, grabbing hundreds of elements. It seems that I need to test each element before I assign, so I changed it to this:

```
String name = null;

if( doc.select("h1#name").first() != null && doc.select("h1#name").first().text() != null ))
    name = doc.select("h1#name").first.text();
```

Is there a better way to do it? I'm just learning Java, and my background is in Perl, where I'd do something like this:

```
my $name = $doc->select("h1#name")->text if $doc->select("h1#name");
```

It's not a big deal, since my code does work for me. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this in Java.

Comment: That code actually won't work as-is, you would need other code to assign to the variable in the case when the element did not exist. So, what do you want to happen when the element does not exist? It's impossible to refactor your code without knowing that.

Comment: It's going into a database that allows for null in the name column (for example). Therefore, if it is not defined in the DOM, then I don't want to insert anything for it. I have yet to get to the Java PostgreSQL part of my code, but I figure I'd push values to an array and bind them, or (like DBIx::Class in Perl) if a variable has no value then nothing is inserted for the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not come arround checking all objects you go throuth to access the value you want.

To translate your perl syntax into java I would use the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

```
name = doc.select("h1#name").first() != null ? 
            doc.select("h1#name").first().text() : null
```

There is no need to check `doc.select("h1#name).first().text() != null` too unless you have a non null value in name and you don't want to override it with null.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a utility method, something like this:

```
Document mDocument;

(...)

String getElementTextOrNull (String cssQuery) {
    Element e = mDocument.select(cssQuery).first();

    if (e == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return e.text();
    }
}
```

Then, you can eliminate a lot of boilerplate and repetition, so your code simply becomes:

```
String name = getElementTextOrNull("h1#name");
```

You can also do other things in that method, like checking if the text is empty or if it is valid.

Of course, this may be impractical if you only get the text of a specific element once, but this is what I would suggest otherwise. Personally, I also think this is neater and more concise than the ternary operator solution proposed in the other answer.